# How to save colorized output text from terminal to local file?

Tags: python, rich

I'm using Python rich to print colorful texts onto the terminal. The code I used is something like this:

```py
from rich import print

print(f'[bold]Param Not Found[/bold]: [yellow]{key}[/yellow] in Section [cyan]{sec}[/cyan]')
```

The output in terminal looks like:

[image]

My question is, how can I save the colorized text from terminal to a local file (for example an html file, or Word, OneNote, etc.)? I tried copy them directly from Windows Terminal into Word, but the color is missing.

Comment: Have you tried opening [settings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install#settings-json-file) and changing the [copyFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/interaction#text-format-when-copying) setting to true?

Comment: @NickODell It worked! But I was thinking if there is a function in rich to directly output the text into an html file or something

Comment: Have you tried [export_html()](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/console.html?highlight=html#rich.console.Console.export_html)?

Comment: Are you asking how to save output when running the program, or how to copy text from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `rich.console` module as follows:

```py
from rich.console import Console

console = Console(record=True)

console.print(f"[bold]Param Not Found[/bold]: [yellow]{key}[/yellow] in Section [cyan]{sec}[/cyan]")

print(console.export_html())
# Use `console.save_html("path to file")` to save it to a file
```

Yields:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.r1 {font-weight: bold}
.r2 {color: #808000; text-decoration-color: #808000; font-weight: bold}
.r3 {color: #808000; text-decoration-color: #808000}
.r4 {color: #008080; text-decoration-color: #008080; font-weight: bold}
.r5 {color: #008080; text-decoration-color: #008080}
body {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <pre style="font-family:Menlo,'DejaVu Sans Mono',consolas,'Courier New',monospace"><code><span class="r1">Param Not Found</span>: <span class="r2">{</span><span class="r3">key</span><span class="r2">}</span> in Section <span class="r4">{</span><span class="r5">sec</span><span class="r4">}</span>
</code></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

More documentation about it [here](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/console.html?highlight=html#rich.console.Console.export_html)